# Как боту в телеграмм собирать информацию inline кнопки и отправлять их список когда нужно?

Tags: telebot, бот, telegram

Начал кодить недавно, делаю телеграмм бота для доставки и не знаю, как мне собирать информацию с inlinebutton и отправлять ее? Например, человек выбирает пиццу (фото снизу), нажимает на кнопку, а бот запоминает его выбор и после, по требованию показа списка заказа, он бы отправлял сообщение с выбранными пиццами. Бьюсь уже 3 дня с этим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая библиотека?

Comment: Пишу на Питоне используя telebot

Comment: ast и startswith позволят получить данные из сообщения в callback https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175928/234134